# Preventing the final segment in a linerenderer from being stiff?

Tags: c#, physics, line-renderer

I am creating a fishing pole, and have the script that draws the line -mostly- worked out using verlet physics. However, the final segment is stiff. The code follows an old Unity3D Subreddit post.

[Best way to do fishing line](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/1kx1hp/best_way_to_do_fishing_line/)

I was able to read through the advice, and came up with a similar set of classes. They seem to work pretty well, though I have to prewarm the line on startup. My main issue is that my version attaches to two targets.

The first is the pole end, which seems fine, but the final segment is the hook. The last segment for it remains 'stiff', while the rest of the line curves properly. I'm not one hundred percent sure how to fix this, and advice would be much appreciated. The issue appears to be the way I'm setting the final target, but I'm not sure how to normalize it all. The code follows a picture of the stiff segment:

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LineParticle  {
    public Vector3 pos;
    public Vector3 oldPos;
    public Vector3 Accel = new Vector3(0, -1.95f, 0);
}

using UnityEngine;

public class Line : MonoBehaviour {

    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    LineParticle[] lineLength;
    public Transform targetObject;
    public float lineRest = 0.8f;
    public int lineSegmentCount = 30;
    private Transform tc;

    private bool isReady = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        tc = transform;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = lineSegmentCount;
        lineLength = new LineParticle[lineSegmentCount];

        for(int i = 0; i < lineSegmentCount; i++)
        {
            lineLength[i] = new LineParticle();

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 450; i++)
        {
            loopRun();
        }

        isReady = true;
    }

    private void Verlet(LineParticle p, float dt)
    {
        Vector3 temp = p.pos;
        p.pos += p.pos - p.oldPos + (p.Accel * dt * dt);
        p.oldPos = temp;
    }

    private void PoleConstraint(LineParticle p1, LineParticle p2, float restLength)
    {
        Vector3 delta = p2.pos - p1.pos;
        float deltaLength = delta.magnitude;

        float diff = (deltaLength - restLength) / deltaLength;

        p1.pos += delta * diff * .5f;
        p2.pos -= delta * diff * .5f;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isReady)
        {
            loopRun();
        }
    }

    private void loopRun()
    {
        lineLength[0].pos = tc.position;

        for (int i = 0; i < lineLength.Length; i++)
        {
            LineParticle lp = lineLength[i];

            Verlet(lp, 0.8f * Time.deltaTime);

            int testLP = i + 1;

            for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
            {
                if (testLP < lineLength.Length - 1)
                {
                    LineParticle lp2 = lineLength[testLP];
                    PoleConstraint(lp, lp2, lineRest);
                }

                if (i == lineSegmentCount - 1)
                {
                    lineLength[i].pos = targetObject.position;
                }

                lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, lp.pos);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cam you describe or include images that show the symptoms of this "stiffness"? A clear example of what's wrong can make it much faster to identify the right fix.

Comment: I added a snapshot of it. You can see the first segments are following the rendered path, then the last stretches out solid.

Answer (score 1):

you have width curve in **LineRenderer Component**. you can simply add nodes to it ad change width along it.

if you look for a whole curve, something like bezier curve is suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Wrong operator - testLP < lineLength should be <=.